# How to Force SMB Legacy Mode Version 1 SMB1 In Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: files, samba, versions, sharing

I hope someone can help me figure this out.
In previous versions of Ubuntu I could lower the security of samba server with something like this.

```
server max protocol = nt1
```

I don't need the extra security features of the latest versions of samba or ubuntu because I am behind a NAT and never open IP/UDP ports 135 through 139 associated with file sharing. I must admit I am getting frustrated with all the security features added to the latest software that I must have to figure out how to disable all of it just to use it in my own house! The free Android apps I use over my WIFI/LAN won't work with the new software and all I want to do is send cellphone pictures to my computer for enhancements or download PDF files created by Libreoffice to my Android tablet. Nothing I will never share over the internet so any suggestions would be appreciated on how to force the latest version of samba on Ubuntu 19.04 to run SMB1 would be greatly appreciated.

Yes, I think I know the risks and know what I am doing. I am already behind a firewall. Thanks in advance. Thanks.

Comment: > The free Android apps I use over my WIFI/LAN won't work with the new software

May be best solution is just change this software?

Answer (score 2):

A Linux samba server is designed to negotiate with the client the best smb dialect to use between two values: "server min protocol" ( which is set to LANMAN1 predating SMB1 ) all the way up to "server max protocol" ( which is set to SMB3 ). Modification of these defaults by adding them to smb.conf should not be necessary to accommodate a client that can only use SMB1 ( aka NT1 ).

I suspect that the version of the samba client on the Android device may be so old that it's the authentication protocol that is the problem and not the smb dialect. You might want to set those authentication levels with this in smb.conf - right under the workgroup = WORKGROUP line:

```
lanman auth = yes
ntlm auth = yes
```

Then restart smbd: `sudo service smbd restart`

Or do what adasiko suggested and find something newer for your Android.

Comment: This advice solved my problem thank you. I have a device running an embedded Linux OS in which I cannot update the version of Samba. I was getting permission denied errors when trying to mount samba shares from other devices on my LAN to the embedded Linux OS using the command... mount -t cifs... Adding the two lines above to the smb.conf file on the device containing the share I wanted to connect to solved the problem.

Comment: Awesome, it was helpful. I was using Mi 360 home camera and earlier, i was able to store videos at NAS but since last few years, unable to store mi camera videos at NAS as smb upgraded to latest version and required configs were not in place to support backward compatibility for older devices using smb1.
Many thanks for this post. 

Answer (score 2):

Thank you very much for this thread... let me explain.

I have a Mi 720p camera and it wasn't accepting the user and password of my Samba shares. I was about to give up, but then after reading your posts, I set my samba.conf header like this:

```
    (...)
    client min protocol = NT1
    server min protocol = NT1
    ntlm auth = yes
    lanman auth = yes
    (...)
```

... and now it accepts the username and password, and let's me choose the folder location! Thank you very much, guys!